# How to check the "size" of a DataReader? (C#)

Tags: c#, datareader

I have this code here:

```
//dr is a IDataReader
while (dr.Read())
{
    //do something
}
```

Sometimes, I get the error **Runtime Error: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.** when calling the Read() method. I checked my DB and noticed that this is always true if there are no entries in my table. How do I avoud this?

Thanks :)

Comment: What's your query, and where *exactly* does the exception occur?

Comment: Got any calculated columns in there? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163363.aspx

Comment: I think there may be more code than you're letting on.. is the exception really thrown at `Read()` ?

Comment: Yeah, at Read(), I debugged...

Comment: Who voted this down?  Leave a comment, foo'!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's actually your query that's causing the error, not the `IDataReader`.  Try and run your query in SQL directly, see if you can get the same error.  Also, have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163363.aspx), you are not the first one to experience that error.